# Deployed along or to?

Tags: prepositions

> Soldiers were deployed **along** or **to** the boarder of the country.

In the above sentence, should I use deployed **along** or **to**? What difference does each preposition make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either choice is correct and idiomatic. As you guessed, the meaning is different. A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: to vs. along]

Answer (score 4):

- "To" suggests that they were all sent to the same location, somewhere on the coast.
- "Along" would suggest that the soldiers were strategically placed to cover the whole length of the border.

PS It's spelled "border" - a "boarder" is someone who lives in your spare room.